# Server for new site fails server-check

Tags: server, requirements

Client purchased package on Web Hosting Canada. I have other clients using this company. I launched the site but /admin gives me Internal Server Error and phperrors.log says

`PHP Fatal error:  [snuffleupagus][disabled_function] Aborted execution on call of the function 'function_exists', because its argument '$function_name' content (proc_open) matched a rule in /home/***/vendor/craftcms/server-check/server/requirements/requirements.php on line 174`

Deleted /vendor and did `composer install` again but did not help.

I added [server-check](https://github.com/craftcms/server-check) files and it shows same error.

Site works locally and my staging server. I have other clients using same host company. What is missing from this client's server set up ([link to phpinfo](https://royalcan.com/phpinfo.php))?

Craft CMS 3.7.38, php 7.4.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host cpanel had 3 different places to do php version selection. While the phpinfo said 7.4 one of the others was set to 7.3. Just had to make sure all said 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, most likely, is that your hosting has disabled the required function for CraftCMS(possible for security reasons), namely [proc_open()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

You must ask the host to enable it or do it yourself if the hosting allows.